# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of integral operator

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying  to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for the following integral operator in $L^{2}[0,1]$:
$T:H \rightarrow H$ is defined as follows:

$$ T[f(x)]= \int_{1-x}^{1} f(t) dt $$.

Here is my procedure until now:

Let $g(x)$ be an eigenvector associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda$, then
$$T[g(x)]  = \lambda g(x) $$.

Solving this problem is equivalent to solving the following integral equation
$$\int_{1-x}^{1} g(t) dt - \lambda g(x) = 0 $$

Differentiating twice the previous equation, we get

$$ g(1-x)=\lambda \frac{dg(x) }{dx}  $$

But i couldn't find any way to solve the last differential equation. Is the previous procedure correct? And is there any way to solve the last equation?

Comment: If you let $\tau = 1-t$, doesn’t $T$ simply become an integral of $f$? Then the eigenfunction is the exponential.

Comment: @player100 you are right, i did not notice that.

Answer (score 3):

By differentiating of equation $g(1-x)=\lambda g'(x)$, we get $-g'(1-x)=\lambda g''(x)$, from where $\lambda^2 g''(x)+g(x)=0$ (it's obvious that $\lambda\ne0$). By adding boundary conditions $g(0)=g'(1)=0$ and solving the obtained Sturm-Liouville problem we get $g_n(x)=\sin\mu_nx$, $\mu_n=\dfrac{1}{\lambda_n}$, $\mu_n=\dfrac{\pi}{2}+\pi n$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: It follows from the equation $g(1-x)=\lambda g'(x)$, whose left-hand side is differentiable almost everywhere.

Comment: In fact, strict justifications are not needed here, because you can try to solve the problem in an "illegal" way, and then substitute the answer into the original equation and make sure that it is fulfilled.

Comment: Well, not quite because you might miss some solutions doing it "illegally."

Comment: Not in this case. Here we turn to the corollary each time, i.e. set of solutions can only expand. Although, you probably meant some discontinuous solutions, then yes, they can get lost.

Comment: You still don't know you have them all, at least not with some rigorous justification. All you know is that the eigenfunctions form a countable set. And now if you are going to appeal to a corollary, then I guess you are being rigorous right? Your answer is fine though. Glad to upvote-

Comment: I edit my comment, because I understood which case you meant.

Comment: @Matematleta what was the mistake with your previous answer? I thought it was correct

Comment: @CristhianMartinez08 In theory you have to solve an infinite system of initial values problems. Namely, If $\lambda=0$ then $g(1-x)=0$ which forces $g=0.$ If not then, letting $u=1-x,$ we have 

$g(u)=-\lambda g'(u): g(1)=0$

$g'(u)=-\lambda g''(u)\Rightarrow g(u)=\lambda^2g''(u):g(1)=g'(1)=0$

$g''(u)=-\lambda g'''(u)\Rightarrow g(u)=-\lambda^3g'''(u): g(1)=g'(1)=g''(1)=0$ and so on. The Sturm-Lioville theory says it suffices to solve the second order diff eq as in this answer.

Comment: @Matematleta im sorry if the following question is trivial. But i have a doubt concerning the change of variable $u=1-x$, why the resulting differential equation is $g'(u) =-\lambda g(u)$ instead of $g'(u)=-\lambda g(1-u)$

Comment: @CristhianMartinez08 $u=1-x$ so $\frac{dg }{dx}=-\frac{dg }{du}$ right? So we just substitute in $g(1-x)=\lambda \frac{dg(x) }{dx}$.

Comment: @Matematleta thanks, I understand it now